# css: making central element of maximum width available without tables

Tags: html, css

I having a hard time getting the central element in a line to take the maximum available width. My central element is the `url_submit_input` element, in this example:

```css
div.url_submit_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
span.url_submit_title {
  display: inline-block;
}
.url_submit_input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.url_submit_button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="url_submit_wrapper">
  <span class="url_submit_title">URL:</span>
  <input class="url_submit_input" name="url" type="text">
  <input class="url_submit_button" type="submit" value=" Submit ">
</div>
```

The output I am trying to get, is:

```
URL: [                  maximum width                ] [SUBMIT]
```

Also, when viewed with a mobile phone (i.e, media query with screen width < 600) , I need it to look like this:

```
URL:
[                       maximum width                ]
[ SUBMIT ]
```

How should this be done without relying on tables? The code I posted only renders the mobile version but not desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.url_submit_wrapper {display: inline-flex;}`

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks! it works, however I am seeing this is a new feature and not all the browsers support it.